# No puedo usar los comandos de los paquetes instalados con NPM y Node

Tags: nodejs, npm, instalacion, paquetes-npm

Hice algunas instalaciones de forma global en *node(v18.12.1)* y *npm(8.19.2)*

Ejecutando *npm list -g --depth 0* pude comprobar que si se encuentran instalados:

```
C:\Users\Victor\AppData\Roaming\npm
+-- @angular/cli@15.0.4
+-- @ionic/cli@6.20.6
+-- @nestjs/cli@9.1.8
`-- yarn@1.22.19
```

Pero ninguno de los comandos de estos CLI´s se reconocen(salvo el de ionic).
uso **Windows 11**, y esto me pasa desde el usuario principal y del secundario que suelo usar para desarrollo.

Answer (score 0):

Verifica que en tu variables de entorno de sistema tengas agregados los path de cada uno de ellos.
En caso de angular: C:\Tu_USER\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@angular\cli\bin
Una vez agregado, por sea caso, cierras tu terminal y lo vuelves a abrir.